# Mean value/Rolle's theorem exercise: show $f'(x)=\cos x$ for infinitely many $x$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $f(n \pi)=0$ for any integer $n$.

prove there exist infintely many realy number $x$ such that $f'(x)=\cos x$

could you please let me know any sketch of this using mean value or Rolle's theorem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $g(x)=f(x)-\sin x$. Then, it is also true that $g(n\pi)=0$ for any integer $n$. Thus, by the mean value theorem, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, there is $x_n\in((n-1)\pi,n\pi)$ such that
$$
0=\frac{g(n\pi)-g((n-1)\pi)}{n\pi-(n-1)\pi}=g'(x_n)=f'(x_n)-\cos(x_n).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $g(x) := f(x) - \sin x$. note that $g(n\pi) = 0$ for any integer $n$ and also that $g'(x) = f'(x) - \cos x$, i.e. $g'(x) = 0 \iff f'(x) = \cos x$. Now, look at $g(x)$ on the interval $[n\pi, (n+1)\pi]$. Why does $g'(x)=0$ at least once on the open interval $(n\pi, (n+1)\pi)$? Once you see this, you can see that you can do this for any $n$, so it happens infinitely many times.